# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this form working on Localhost but when I upload to my shared hosting they throw **VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67**.

Here the code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i> Login
            </button>

            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>

            <a href="{{ url('/auth/facebook') }}">FB Login</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I added this:  `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />` in to my head tags, but it's not working. The token is okay, appears on the form when I inspect with Google Chrome Inspector. If someone can help on this I am really stuck here.

Comment: you can try this two commands
`php artisan clear:cache
php artisan route:cache`

Comment: If you have written your own `VerifyCsrfToken.php`, please show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

Check your session directory for correct permissions, it might be help.

```
rm -f {your_web_app}/storage/framework/sessions/*
```

Answer (score 1):

You properly have trouble with session storage
**Solution 1**: Use database session driver instead of file session driver 
***- In .env***

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

***- Run command***

```
php artisan session:table
```

***- Then***

```
php artisan migrate
```

Test again 
***Solution 2***: Continue using file session driver. Make sure you have writing permission on **storage** folder. Try

```
chmod 755 -R storage
```

Comment: Hi @KmasterYC, i dont have console access. Its shared hosting. I go to try that on localhost. Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry. I have no idea else

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ session()->getToken() }}">
```

In your view blade.

Comment: put this line once. just below `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">`, i think no need to use ` {{ csrf_field() }}` in your form.